# Image Dataset on Corrosion of Metals

Tags: data-request, images

I need an Image Data set on Corroded Metals due to rust. I was searching for it but am unable to find one. Is there any open Dataset of Corroded Metal Images

Answer (score 2):

There is a dataset from IBM IoT that has corrosion images, but I don't know how extensive.

https://github.com/IBM/Predictive-Industrial-Visual-Analysis

https://github.com/IBM/Predictive-Industrial-Visual-Analysis/tree/master/vr-image-data

---

I also found this paper, which cites that the images where given from an industry partner. You might try to contact either the authors, or the company.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03138.pdf

> A large dataset of 250 images with segmentations labelled by undergraduates...
>
> The authors wish to acknowledge the support provided by Woodside Petroleum in providing images of corrosion.

[image]